# What is the fastest way to copy an unsafe byte* buffer in c#?

Tags: c#, performance, buffer, unsafe

I'm currently designing an image processing application, using .NET Framework 4.0 for extended compatibility purposes.

I'm wondering if I could find a way to copy a buffer to another one faster than a trivial `for` or `Parallel.For` loop, given that when the copy is needed, buffers (source and destination) are both`byte*` with a known length.

As I'm using .NET 4.0, I cannot use Buffer.Memcopy.

Comment: .NET 4.0? that was end-of-life in 2015/2016, depending on the OS; I **strongly** suggest the first thing you do is: target a different framework! however: is P/Invoke an option? You could use an `extern` call to `memcpy`, specifically `[DllImport("msvcrt.dll", EntryPoint = "memcpy", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError = false)] private static extern IntPtr MemCpy(IntPtr dest, IntPtr src, UIntPtr count);`

Comment: I knew I would hear that kind of screams about 4.0... The thing is that a former version of the software is still running on a bunch of Windows XP with people that won't upgrade their system. Anyway thanks, I'm going to check memcpy2

Comment: I added the P/Invoke definition for you. You've also made me even more afraid, now that you've mentioned XP. Honestly, you aren't helping your client/users by helping them stay on XP.

Comment: Why can't you use Memcopy?  It is a windows dll : https://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/urlmon/CopyMemory.html

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing/blob/master/KGySoft.Drawing/Drawing/MemoryHelper.cs) can be useful, also from an image processing library (disclaimer: mine). But in .NET 3.5-4.5 it simply uses `Kernel32.CopyMemory`. The `Parallel.For` is recommended only for larger chunks, eg. one row at once. You can find examples for that in the library.

Comment: Well, it looks like `memcpy` works fine, with a measured improvement of speed around 20% on a quad core I5, vs. my former `Paralle.For`, thanks everyone.